# Show sidebar again in TextWrangler

Tags: textwrangler

It seems I'm blind.

I can't find the option to display the sidebar again to display all open files. Where can find it?

Comment: it' seem's this is called 'project window'. It appears again after restart. But after closing the sidebar again, I can't find a option to mange the open files as a project again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TextWrangler > View > Show Files ⌘0

Comment: excelente you are great